# The fastest solution to port the php function addslashes to c++

Tags: c++, addslashes

> string addslashes ( string $str ) 
>   Returns a string with backslashes
>   before characters that need to be quoted in database queries etc.
>   These characters are single quote ('), double quote ("), backslash ()
>   and NUL (the NULL byte).

I'm working on a c++ equivalent of this php function. Right now my function uses nested replace calls, where I replace \ with \\ and **'** with **\'**. It's not pretty at all and it's very slow too.

What is the best solution using **only** the standard c++ libs and functions? I mean the absolute fastest way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go over the string in a single pass (`for` loop) and `switch` on each character.
2. When encountering a character that needs escaping, push a backslash into the output buffer
3. Push current character into the output buffer.

Use a `std::ostringstream` for the output buffer.

This is very efficient (single pass, buffered output) and straightforward to implement. To make it yet more efficient, directly use a `std::string` as the output buffer, append the characters using `push_back`, and `reserve` a sufficiently large capacity (e.g. `1.5 * input.length()`) in front of the loop.

Comment: This may be made faster by avoiding reallocations by making the output buffer of a correct size, for instance `stream.str().reserve(input_len*1.5)` if you know the length upfront. It's also possible to do first pass on input to count the output string's length, then do a second pass with the output of required size. IDK if saving on reallocations would compensate the second pass.

Comment: @Kos `stream.str().reserve(…)` is a nonsense operation, since `str()` returns a copy. I don’t know how to reserve capacity in a `stringstream`. Of course, you could directly `push_back` into a `string` with a reserved capacity.